# Epoch time in Java

Tags: java

I would like to represent 1 day from current date as epoch time. Today's date is Oct 20th. So I would like to get the epoch time for tomorrow. I have the below code -

```
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    cal.setTime(new Date());
    cal.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, 1);
    int time = (int) ((cal.getTimeInMillis())/1000);
    System.out.println("TIME IS: " +time);
```

So I basically want to add 1 day to current day of the year i.e. Oct 20th, and represent that as epoch time. I am displaying the time in seconds, hence the divide by 1000. The result for the program is 1413958770. 1 day from today would be 86400 seconds. How exactly does epoch time work? I understand it gives time since 1970, but if that is indeed the case, the value can't be that small :-). Am I missing something here?

Comment: Epoch is a fixed point in time, which is represented by `0`.  You would need to subtract the millisecond representation of today from the millisecond representation of tomorrow...

Comment: Why do you think the value cant be that small? (1413958770/86400) = 16365 days. 16365/365 = 44 years.

Comment: As @MadProgrammer says `cal.getTimeInMillis()` gives you the number to Epoch; you need to get both numbers: today's number (in relation to Epoch) and tomorrow's number (in relation to Epoch) and subtract them

Comment: Since posting, the `Calendar` class was supplanted by the modern *java.time* class `ZonedDateTime` as defined by JSR 310. Avoid using the legacy date-time classes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If "today" is the epoch, then it should "represent" `0`, any time measured from or compared to "now" should be subtracted from it, for example...

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.setTime(new Date());
long now = cal.getTimeInMillis();
cal.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, 1);

long then = cal.getTimeInMillis();
long secondsFromEpoch = (then - now) / 1000;

System.out.println(secondsFromEpoch);
```

Answer (score 5):

Let's do some basic math:

- a minute has 60 seconds
- an hour has 60 minutes
- a day has 24 hours
- a year has 365 days

  ```
  1413958770 / (60 * 60 * 365 * 24) = 44,8
  ```

([test it](https://www.google.fr/search?q=1413958770%20%2F%20%2860%20*%2060%20*%20365%20*%2024%29&ie=utf-8))

Add 44,8 years to 1970, and you'll be in 2014. So nothing is wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Unix time or POSIX time or Epoch time is a system for describing instants in time, defined as the number of seconds that have elapsed since 00:00:00 Coordinated Universal Time (UTC), Thursday, 1 January 1970, not counting leap seconds.

In Java, you can simply get it using below statement.

```
long current_time = System.currentTimeMillis() * 1000000L;
```

or

```
long epoch = date.getTime();
```

Answer (score 0):

There have been [a couple dozen epochs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epoch_(reference_date)#Notable_epoch_dates_in_computing) used by various computer systems. The beginning of 1970 UTC is common, but certainly not the only epoch in current use. And various systems track time since epoch using whole seconds, milliseconds, microseconds, and nanoseconds. So rather than use the vague term "epoch time", it would be more useful to directly say what you want. In this case it seems to be "whole seconds since beginning of 1970 UTC until tomorrow".

Perhaps you were just curious about the math and numbers. But if you were serious about the date-time work, then I advise using the [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) library or the java.time package in Java 8.

Time zone is crucial when taking about dates and defining the beginning of a day.

Here is example code using Joda-Time 2.5.

```
DateTimeZone zone = DateTimeZone.forID( "Australia/Melbourne" );
DateTime tomorrowStart = DateTime.now( zone ).plusDays( 1 ).withTimeAtStartOfDay();
long secondsSinceUnixEpoch = ( tomorrowStart.getMillis() / 1000 );
```

Answer (score 0):

## tl;dr

```
ZonedDateTime
    .now( ZoneId.of( "Asia/Tokyo" ) )           // Current moment as seen through the clock & calendar in use in Tokyo Japan.
    .toLocalDate()                              // Today
    .plusDays( 1 )                              // Tomorrow
    .atStartOfDay( ZoneId.of( "Asia/Tokyo" ) )  // Start of tomorrow.
    .toInstant()                                // Start of tomorrow in Tokyo as seen in UTC.
    .getEpochSecond()                           // Count of whole seconds since 1970-01-01T00:00Z until the start of tomorrow in Tokyo.
```

### *java.time*

Avoid using the terribly flawed legacy class `java.util.Calendar`. Use only *java.time* classes defined in JSR 310.

You said:

> Today's date is Oct 20th. So I would like to get the epoch time for tomorrow.

To determine *tomorrow*, we need to know *today*. To determine a date, you must specify a time zone. For any given moment, the **date varies** around the globe by time zone. It is “tomorrow” in Tokyo Japan while simultaneously “yesterday” in Toledo Ohio US.

```
ZoneId zCasablanca = ZoneId.of( "Africa/Casablanca" ) ;
ZonedDateTime nowInCasablanca = ZonedDateTime.now( z ) ;
LocalDate todayCasablanca = zdt.toLocalDate() ;
LocalDate tomorrowCasablanca = todayCasablanca.plusDays( 1 ) ;
```

Get the first moment of tomorrow as seen in that time zone.

```
ZonedDateTime zdtStartOfTomorrowCasablanca = tomorrowCasablanca.atStartOfDay( zCasablanca ) ;
```

By "epoch time" I assume you mean a count of milliseconds since the first moment of 1970 as seen with an offset from UTC of zero hours-minutes-seconds (1970-01-01T00:00Z).

To get that count, we must first adjust our moment from a time zone to UTC (an offset of zero). Simply extracting an `Instant` does that.

```
Instant instant = zdtStartOfTomorrowCasablanca.toInstant() ;
```

Interrogate that `Instant` for a count since 1970-01-01T00:00Z.

```
long secondsSinceStartOf1970Utc = instant.getEpochSecond() ;
```

Or you may want milliseconds.

```
long millisSinceStartOf1970Utc = instant.toEpochMilli() ;
```

Either way, you may have data loss involved. An `Instant` resolves to nanoseconds. So any microseconds or nanoseconds in your `Instant` object are being ignored by code above.